# Is there anyway Javascript or php can be used to tell me the type of the link? ( xml or html )

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml, wsdl

I have a webpage that generates links. Sometimes theses links are working WSDL (XML type) and sometimes it just shows an `<h>` this wsdl is an invalid WSDL `</h>`.

Is there anyway I can know before it opens if this link is an XML (working wsdl) or HTML (invalid wsdl)?

Comment: Can you add a [mcve] of the issue?

Comment: If in doubt, read **[ask]**

Comment: Did you check if the link you're loading returns a different http status code for invalid WSDL? That might be easier than checking the data...

Comment: @BillyNate Can you please elaborate on the subject ? I don't quite know how to check the status code.

Comment: Elaboration can be found as an answer. [Please let us know](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the invalid XML is a warning/error (in HTML) because the requested URL could not be served as expected.
On all pages on the web not only the (visible) data is served (HTML, XML, etc.), but also the [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers). One of the headers is the [status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes): We've all seen the famous 404, but when everything goes alright the server gives a status 200.
If you would load the contents of a URL to a variable in PHP, you can also determine the status code, for example:

```php
// Load the url:
$dataFromURL = file_get_contents($url);

// Loop over all response headers and look for the status code:
foreach($http_response_header as $header)
{
  // Store the status code into the $code variable:
  sscanf($header, 'HTTP/%*d.%*d %d', $code);
}

if($code == 200)
{
  // Everything fine, do the usual
}
else
{
  // Exception, do something else
}
```

You can do something similar in JavaScript (I used jQuery to keep it a bit simpler):

```
$.ajax({
  success: function(data, textStatus, xhr)
  {
    $('body').append($('<p>').text(xhr.status));
  },
  complete: function(xhr, textStatus)
  {
    $('body').append($('<p>').text(xhr.status));
  }
});
```

If, somehow, the server always gives you status 200, you can look for the [`content-type` header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) instead. This will tell you if `text/html` is being served, or `text/xml`.
(In php use `sscanf($header, 'Content-Type: %[^]]', $mime)` instead, or in jQuery use `xhr.getResponseHeader('content-type')` instead of `xhr.status`).
Keep in mind though; this still is what the server tells you to expect, it might be "lying" to you...

If all of this does not work for you, you might want to parse the HTML (`<h>`) as XML and look at the root element and check if the node is an `h` or something you're actually looking for.

Answer (score -1):

If the link is as a string, you should be able to use this:

```
if (strpos($link, 'https:/') == false) {
    isHTTP = true;
}
else{isXML = true;}
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply.
This will not work because all of the links generated begin with Https:/.   However what i noticed is that when i open a valid link and right-click on the page it automatically saves as XML file. And when i try to save-as an invalid page it saves as .html file. So there has to be something i can do to tell them apart.

Comment: When you right-click on the page and select "saves as" there is a drop table on the botton that let you save as httml only. Print to help guide: https://prnt.sc/k8t0d0

Comment: Can you give an exemple of a link?